# how can I show close button in non leaner ads in ima3 plugin using VAST tag?

Tags: angularjs, ads, brightcove, vast

I am struggling on how to show the Close button on non leaner ad in IMA3 plugin using VAST3 tag. currently there is no close button on non leaner banner ads.

Comment: Hey Muthu, are you using brightcove player? Just asking because you tagged as brightcove.

Comment: yes Rafeel, I am using brightcove player